# React Native Packager without watchman

Tags: react-native, watchman, packager

I just started looking into react-native for android development and setup the environment in windows. Then it turns out there's no watchman release for windows.

The react native packager runs without watchman but the app reloads or live reloads doesn't work and I needed to restart react native packager every time I make changes to the code. This takes at least 1 minute for some reason.

Is there anyway to make this more bearable? For e.g. trigger file changes to packager manually or alternative to watchman that works with react native packager.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

hot/manual reloads should work on windows, you should not have to restart the packager too often

Comment: I had just been facing a really stupid error. Did quite a bit of debugging and found out the problem is not with watchman. It's because react packager's directory checking is case-sensitive and my code editor's integrated terminal is loading up directory with small drive letters for some reason. Now it's working like a charm.

Comment: @NayMin where is react-packager's directory?

Comment: I didn't install watchman for Mac and hot-reload still works.